# Access or parse podspec via swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have created *cocoapods* package - my workspace now contains *MyPackage.podspec* file where is stored basic info about my package eg. version. Can I somehow parse/access this file via swift so I could use data in my code? I want to send a version of my package via HTTP headers generated by my package, so I know on my backend which version of a package is used.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use app version and build for that purposes

Comment: `Can I somehow parse/access this file via swift` No. The pods are compiled at the same time that your own code is compiled. The app itself doesn't see the pods - the pods are used to make the app.